# Setup Confluence JDBC connection

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jdbc, confluence

I'm trying to set up a new install of confluence, the database is on the same server and I have correctly installed the JDBC connector. When I go through the database setup I get the following error when entering my database username and password:

```
Setup Database Failed

The following error(s) occurred:
Configuring the database failed. Couldn't create the database schema.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'confluencedbuser'@'localhost' 
(using password: YES)
```

I have checked and flushed the privileges of that user and it is granted all privileges on that database. I'm not sure what's going on here. Any ideas? (Haven't had much luck with Google)

Thanks a bunch :)

EDIT:

Here is the output from the atlassian-confluence.log if that helps.

```
2014-05-22 19:36:29,407 INFO [localhost-startStop-2][com.atlassian.confluence.lifecycle] contextDestroyed Stopping Confluence
2014-05-22 19:36:29,409 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] [atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager] shutdown Shutting down the plugin system
2014-05-22 19:37:05,089 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] [com.atlassian.confluence.lifecycle] contextInitialized Starting Confluence 5.5.1 [build 5509 based on commit hash df269dcb09b33d7c337c07d822c97aeb564430a7]
2014-05-22 19:37:07,630 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] [atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager] init Initialising the plugin system
2014-05-22 19:37:07,697 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [org.twdata.pkgscanner.InternalScanner] findInPackage Unable to find any resources for package 'bucket*'
2014-05-22 19:37:08,552 WARN [localhost-startStop-1] [org.twdata.pkgscanner.InternalScanner] findInPackage Unable to find any resources for package 'org/xml'
2014-05-22 19:37:13,422 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] [atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager] init Plugin system started in 0:00:05.790
```

Comment: did you try to connect to the db with another client then confluence?

Comment: @deterministicFail no, what would you recommend as the best way to do that?

Comment: just test the connection with that user from another client like sqlyog or mysql workbench. if you still cant connect, its a problem you have to solve in the database, otherwise its a config problem of confluence

Comment: @deterministicFail tried with sequel pro and got this: Unable to connect to host [censored hostname] because access was denied.

Double-check your username and password and ensure that access from your current location is permitted.

MySQL said: Access denied for user 'confluencedbuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: what is the output for `SHOW GRANTS FOR confluencedbuser`

Comment: mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'confluencedbuser'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for confluencedbuser@localhost                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'confluencedbuser'@'localhost'                       |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `confluencedb`.* TO 'confluencedbuser'@'localhost' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @deterministicFail If I try to access mysql from the command line using mysql -u confluencedbuser -p (password) I get the same access denied message.

Comment: @deterministicFail I can access the database via sequel pro using the root username and password fine. It's something to do with that user.

Comment: are you using the right password? maybe you can try to change it

Comment: @deterministicFail bizarre, I just reset the password and now it's working. I used exactly the same password. It was a generated password and simply copied and pasted every time. Thanks for your help!